# Nullable object must have a value - c#

Tags: c#, null

Tengo esta excepción Nullable object must have a value dentro de mi if, este es el código:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string traHomoclave)
    {
        GetVisitasPortal(traHomoclave);
        var getCookie = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[ToolHelper.KeyCookieLast];
        Response.Cookies.Append(ToolHelper.KeyCookieLast, ToolHelper.SetTheLastVisit(getCookie, traHomoclave), ToolHelper.SetTimeCookie(ToolHelper.DaysCookies));

        TramiteViewModel tramite = new TramiteViewModel();
        tramite.tra_Tramites = new tra_tramites();
        tramite.tra_Tramites.TramitePdf = (bool)tramite.tra_Tramites.TramitePdf;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(traHomoclave))
        {
            tramite = await _tramiteRepository.GetTramiteByHomoClave(traHomoclave);
            ViewBag.Estados = await _baseRepository.GetAllEstados();
            ViewBag.Titulo = tramite.tra_Tramites.traHomoclave;
        }
        else
            return View("~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml");


        bool ExisteSesion = false;
        string NombreCompleto = "";
        var objSession = _sesionRepository.GetUpdateSession(HttpContext);
        if (objSession != null)
        {
            ExisteSesion = true;
            var objUserCurrent = objSession.master_usuarios.Where(c => c.usuIdRol == 12).FirstOrDefault();
            if (objUserCurrent != null)
            {
                NombreCompleto += objUserCurrent.usuNombre + " " + objUserCurrent.usuApPaterno + " " + objUserCurrent.usuApMaterno;
            }
        }
        ViewBag.ExisteSesion = ExisteSesion;
        ViewBag.NombreCompleto = NombreCompleto;
        if (tramite.tra_Tramites.TramitePdf == true)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tramite.tra_Tramites.Pdf))
            {
                var urlRedirect = _configuration["urlTramite"] + tramite.tra_Tramites.Pdf;
                return Redirect(urlRedirect);
            }
        }
        return View(tramite);
    }
```

Al principio en mi if(tramite.tra_Tramites.TramitePdf == true) me traía la excepción de objeto no instanciado, por lo que puse esta variable de esta forma al principio:

```
TramiteViewModel tramite = new TramiteViewModel();
        tramite.tra_Tramites = new tra_tramites();
        tramite.tra_Tramites.TramitePdf = (bool)tramite.tra_Tramites.TramitePdf;
```

Depurando se que mi variable tramite.tra_Tramites.TramitePdf traé un null, pero no logró determinar el porque, por lo que en mi vista me aparece en blanco.

El cual agradecería mucho de alguna orientación o comentarios.

Gracias.

Comment: Que tipo de dato es TramitePdf  en la clase tra_tramites, si es `bool?` puedes cambialo por `bool` y ponle un valor default `= false`, ejemplo: `public bool TramitePdf  {get;set;} = false;`

Comment: Hola @Mad96, puedes decirme si la respuesta dada te resulto util, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que `tramite.tra_Tramites.TramitePdf` puede tener valor null y tu tratas de realizar un casting a `bool`, te sugiero validar en este caso:

```
   TramiteViewModel tramite = new TramiteViewModel();
    tramite.tra_Tramites = new tra_tramites();
    if(tramite.tra_Tramites.TramitePdf == null){
      tramite.tra_Tramites.TramitePdf = false;
    }
    tramite.tra_Tramites.TramitePdf = (bool)tramite.tra_Tramites.TramitePdf;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, efectivamente: tramite.tra_Tramites.TramitePdf trae un NULL, sin embargo de aquí ya no se que más puedo implementar. Ya que en teoría al traer algo en esa línea es cuando debería pasar en el if que está al final.

Answer (score 0):

Para comprobar si los datos son nulos o no puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
if(tramite.HasValue && tramite.tra_Tramites.HasValue && tramite.tra_Tramites.TramitePdf.HasValue)
{
    //Tu código
}
```

Lo que se hace aquí es usar la **propiedad HasValue** que tienen todos los **objetos nulleables**, está propiedad devuelve **true** si el objeto no es nulo, es decir si tiene algún valor, caso contrario devuelve **false**.

Tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
if(tramite.HasValue && tramite.tra_Tramites.HasValue && tramite.tra_Tramites.TramitePdf.HasValue)
{
    if (tramite.tra_Tramites.TramitePdf == true)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tramite.tra_Tramites.Pdf))
        {
            var urlRedirect = _configuration["urlTramite"] + tramite.tra_Tramites.Pdf;

            return Redirect(urlRedirect);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, lo probaré. Cómo otra pregunta, el if que comenta iría donde se encuentra el if que está al final antes del return??

Comment: @Mad96 revisa lo nuevo que puse